Prove the Ramsey number for k matchings
Prove the Ramsey number of $k$ matchings is $3k-1$. Do you have any hints on how to solve it? Here what I mean is the smallest number $N$ such that any two colorings of the edges of $K_N$, we can find a monochromatic matching of size $k$

Please define what you mean by "the Ramsey number of $k$ matchings." (Oe "K-matchings" as in the title.)

Proof that $N\geq3k-1$:
Consider the graph $K_{2k-1} \bigsqcup \overline {K}_{k-1}$ (the disjoint union of a complete graph on $2k-1$ vertices and a graph with no edges on $k-1$ vertices).  This has no matching of size $k$, as that would require at least $2k$ vertices of positive degree.  Conversely the complement of the graph has no matching of size $k$, as each of the $k$ edges of the matching would be incident to at least one of the $k-1$ vertices   in $\overline {K}_{k-1}$, violating the pigeonhole principle.
Thus we have a subgraph of $K_{3k-2}$ such that neither it, not its complement contain a matching of size $K$.
Proof that $N\leq 3k-1$:
Proceed by induction.  For any graph on $2$ vertices, it is clear that we either have an edge, or the complement of the graph has an edge.  This proves the statement for $k=1$.
Suppose now we have proven the statement, for some value $k$.  Consider any graph on $3k+2$ vertices.  The graph cannot have a vertex of degree $0$, and a vertex of degree $3k+1$, as the graph must either contain, or not contain the edge between two such vertices.
This leaves three possibilities: The graph is the complete graph, the graph has no edges, or the graph has a vertex of degree between $1$ and $3k$.
In the first case we have a matching of size $k+1$ in the graph.  In the second case we have a matching in the complement of the graph of size $k+1$.
In the third case, we have a vertex $x$ of degree between $1$  and $3k$.  Thus we have vertices $y,z$ such that $xy$ is an edge of the graph, and $xz$ is not an edge of the graph.  Using the inductive hypothesis, we can finding a matching of the graph or its complement of size $k$ in the $3k-1$ vertices excluding $x,y,z$.
If the matching of size $k$ lies in the graph, we add the edge $xy$, to get a matching of size $k+1$ in the graph.  If the matching of size $k$ lies in the complement of the graph, we add the edge $xz$, to a get a matching of size $k+1$, in the complement of the graph.
